# Azure Data Factory - add existing pipelines to git

Tags: git, azure, azure-data-factory

We had a bit of a strange situation where Git stopped working in our Azure Data Factory so we published directly to the service.

After rectifying the Git issue I switched to the main branch and my new pipelines I created in the mean time don't appear in the branch.

If I switch to live mode I see them, but what I can't see is how to add them to the main branch?
All the other pipelines are in the main branch, there just doesn't seem to be a way to bring the two together.

Reading online documentation most of it talks about adding Git with a checkbox giving you the ability to add everything in the current data factory to the Git connection you're adding. But, nothing about adding pipelines in the pipeline service to the git branch.

**Service: Azure Data Factory

Repo: Azure DevOps Git**

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: While configuring GIT, did you select the `Import resource into this branch` as in this image: https://i.imgur.com/aPyZb2A.png. and select the brach to which you want to import (main branch) in this case.

Comment: @SaideepArikontham yes they were originally added to the Git repo but then I somehow got disconnected from Git, went ahead and created new pipelines which were not in Git. Now I'm reconnected to git and those pipelines don't appear. If I switch to live mode I can see the new pipelines, but don't know how to add them to the git repo

Comment: While reconnecting, select the import existing resources and select the required branch to which to want to import to. After doing this, once you complete connection, you should be able to see the resources in your GIT